# Language resource

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make my aplication multilingual. But I am having difficulty with getting a string array in the correct language. It works everywhere else in the aplication, but it fails in my navigation drawer. Is there something that I am missing, I think it is related to the context but I am not sure.

The code that I am using is:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Context context = getActivity();

    // Change the application language
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = new Locale("es");
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);

    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBar().getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, res.getStringArray(R.array.drawer_activities)));
    mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
    return mDrawerListView;
}
```

It does successfully get the string array, but it gets the default language which is English. It won't load the other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your strings.xml you should do it like this:

```
<string name="one">one</string>
<string name="two">two</string>
<string name="three">three</string>

<string-array name="numbers">
    <item>@string/one</item>
    <item>@string/two</item>
    <item>@string/three</item>
</string-array>
```

Now you have to do the same thing for other languages (Spanish for example) and you can simply use your strings-es.xml with **uno, dos, tres** using the same pattern as above:

```
<string name="one">uno</string>
<string name="two">dos</string>
<string name="three">tres</string>

<string-array name="numbers">
    <item>@string/one</item>
    <item>@string/two</item>
    <item>@string/three</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: It's not ugly. It's the cleanest way to do it, if you are using multiple languages and string arrays ;) You could of course leave out the string items and write it directly in your string array. That feels kinda clumsy to me however